# Concatenating function outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

How would you do concatenate `headName` and `tailName`?

```
name = input("What is your name? ") 
def headName(name):
    print((name)[:1].upper())
def tailName(name):
    print((name)[1:].lower())
headName = str(headName(name))
tailName = str(tailName(name))
```

Comment: Change `print` to `return` and indent the code properly.

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks but it still doesnt work

Comment: @BhargavRao still doesn't work

Comment: Add `print(headName + tailName)` at the end.

Comment: @BhargavRao done it -- thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by concatenate you mean "glue" the result of the two funcions, since they are strings, you can use the "+" operator

`name = input("What is your name? ") 
def headName(name):
    return((name)[:1].upper())
def tailName(name):
    return((name)[1:].lower())
headName = str(headName(name))
tailName = str(tailName(name))
print(headName+tailName)`